# Meteor Inline Script Errors

Tags: javascript, meteor

We are trying to use an inline  tag in the head of a website for a 3rd party tool (live person chat), and are getting a pretty strange error:

Cannot find module './util/EventsUtil'

Currently we are loading the tag in the same way this post suggested:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-add-a-script-to-head-in-1-3/20295/11

Using this package:

https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-inject-initial/

It does load the script, and the script actually works, until you refresh the page...that is when the error occurs.

Here is the server code:

```
Inject.rawModHtml('inject a script at the beginning of the head', function(html) {
  return html.replace("<head>", "<head> <script type='text/javascript'>window.lpTag=window.lpTag||{},'undefined'==typeof window.lpTag._tagCount?(window.lpTag={wl:lpTag.wl||null,scp:lpTag.scp||null,site:'siteidnumber'||'',section:lpTag.section||'',tagletSection:lpTag.tagletSection||null,autoStart:lpTag.autoStart!==!1,ovr:lpTag.ovr||{},_v:'1.10.0',_tagCount:1,protocol:'https:',events:{bind:function(t,e,i){lpTag.defer(function(){lpTag.events.bind(t,e,i)},0)},trigger:function(t,e,i){lpTag.defer(function(){lpTag.events.trigger(t,e,i)},1)}},defer:function(t,e){0===e?(this._defB=this._defB||[],this._defB.push(t)):1===e?(this._defT=this._defT||[],this._defT.push(t)):(this._defL=this._defL||[],this._defL.push(t))},load:function(t,e,i){var n=this;setTimeout(function(){n._load(t,e,i)},0)},_load:function(t,e,i){var n=t;t||(n=this.protocol+'//'+(this.ovr&&this.ovr.domain?this.ovr.domain:'lptag.liveperson.net')+'/tag/tag.js?site='+this.site);var o=document.createElement('script');o.setAttribute('charset',e?e:'UTF-8'),i&&o.setAttribute('id',i),o.setAttribute('src',n),document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(o)},init:function(){this._timing=this._timing||{},this._timing.start=(new Date).getTime();var t=this;window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent('onload',function(){t._domReady('domReady')}):(window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){t._domReady('contReady')},!1),window.addEventListener('load',function(){t._domReady('domReady')},!1)),'undefined'===typeof window._lptStop&&this.load()},start:function(){this.autoStart=!0},_domReady:function(t){this.isDom||(this.isDom=!0,this.events.trigger('LPT','DOM_READY',{t:t})),this._timing[t]=(new Date).getTime()},vars:lpTag.vars||[],dbs:lpTag.dbs||[],ctn:lpTag.ctn||[],sdes:lpTag.sdes||[],hooks:lpTag.hooks||[],identities:lpTag.identities||[],ev:lpTag.ev||[]},lpTag.init()):window.lpTag._tagCount+=1;</script>");
});
```

We have tested the script (we removed our clients account number from the script for this post) in a static HTML page and it works fine. We just cant seem to identify what it is that is throwing the error and why it will work until the page is refreshed.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! :)

Comment: I think you need to find in your code (or npm module) and see what is importing  './util/EventsUtil'

Comment: Yeah I actually did. Its the 3rd party's (live person) that is using the module. Unfortunately I do not have control over it and when used with a static or WordPress type site, it works fine. The best guess I have is that Meteor is caching their apps code (notice it calls an external file) which calls a local package (note the ./util/EventsUtil) which is not available to the local Meteor filesystem. :(

Comment: There are a couple of things you can do here: 1) submit an issue to the package and 2) fork the package yourself (and fix the bug), and then install your fork into your project 3) Submit a PR for your fix

Comment: Ive done all of the above. Thank you for at the very least validating I am not crazy!